# Invert geometry nodes selection Blender

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, select

[image: geometry_nodes_position_selection_blender]

I have a selection made based on Position and Normal. The distribution should be inverted.
How can I invert it ? [image]

Thank you.

---

[image]

Thank you. This works. But doesn't feel it completely invert the selection, but that might be because of my way of creating the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the distribute points node works on the face domain, you can just invert that with the boolean math not node like this:

[image]